# Detect rapid user activity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating an ASP.Net MVC 5 website. In my website, there is a voting system which is very similar to the one StackOverflow uses. I have successfully created the system in which users submit the votes. However one neat feature of SO is that it prevents users from rapidly clicking vote buttons (i.e. voting too fast). Currently my Vote class is something like this:

```
public class RestaurantReviewVote
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual NormalUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual ItemReview Reivew { get; set; }

    [Range(-1, 1)]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

What I have in mind is to do something like this:

```
rapidActivity = db.Votes.Where(v => v.User.Id == userId && (DateTime.UtcNow - v.Created < THRESHOLD)).Any();
```

However, I think running this everytime a user submits a vote would be too much pressure on the database. (maybe I'm wrong) How can I do it with performance in mind?

PS:
If you think there's a better way to do the voting system, please tell me. I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is reasonable for throttling the votes. You can always cache the last vote time for the user if you don't want to query the database each time.

This could also be an edge case for performance. If the check only occurs when someone is voting, then you're not going to have to incur this penalty on every page load. Chances are you're going to have to do other queries to register a vote anyway, so you could wrap this up in your Vote() method:

(note that you can combine the Where() and the Any() methods)

```
public bool Vote(int restaurantId)
{
    if (db.Votes.Any(v => v.User.Id == userId && (DateTime.UtcNow - v.Created < THRESHOLD)) 
    {
        throw new VoteException("You are voting too quickly");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: YES!! The answer was right in front of me and I didn't see it. I think what I was looking for was caching the latest activity time. This way I can combine these kinds of operations into several categories and cache their time using only the `User` class which I'm gonna get anyway. Thanks for your suggestions and improvements a lot.